# C# class - System.MissingMethodException when in FSI

Tags: c#, f#, missingmethodexception, fsi

I have run in a weird behavior.

I am tring to use a C# library: the [Neo4jClient](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Neo4jClient)

My code in FSI looks like this:

```
#r "Neo4jClient.dll"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"


open System
open Neo4jClient

// Define your library scripting code here
let client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"))
client.Connect()
```

and leads to the following error:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.set_DateParseHandling(Newtonsoft.Json.DateParseHandling)'.
   at Neo4jClient.Serialization.CustomJsonDeserializer.Deserialize[T](String content)
   at Neo4jClient.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsJson[T](HttpContent content, IEnumerable`1 jsonConverters) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\HttpContentExtensions.cs:line 20
   at Neo4jClient.GraphClient.Connect() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\GraphClient.cs:line 188
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0013>.$FSI_0013.main@() in C:\Users\Mattia\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\GenChi\GenChiSnooper\Script.fsx:line 12
```

However, if executed as a F# application, the same code runs properly.

```
open System
open Neo4jClient

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"))
    client.Connect();
    printfn "Went through..."
    printfn "%A" argv
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

I am not sure if this issue is library specific. 
My question is: is there some specific hacking for the use of C# libraries with the FSI?

Tnx.

Comment: Have you also referenced the json dll in fsi?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have also tried to downgrade the json dll

Comment: I assume the missing `dll` for the json is a typo?

Comment: This must be a DLL Hell problem.  Use Fuslogvw.exe and log all the binds to have an idea where the Newtonsoft.Json.dll comes from when you run in FSI.

Comment: Check which version of .net and F# you are using in fsi vs your F# application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run visual studio as Administrator. and reference latest Newtonsof.Json package:

```
#I @"..\packages\Neo4jClient.1.0.0.652\lib\net40"
#I @"..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.2\lib\net45"

#r "Neo4JClient.dll"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
let client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://host:7474/db/data"))
client.Connect()
printfn "conntected"
```

Comment: Running as Admin fixed a problem. I am not sure why though. Thanks.